# how do I make the base64 string neat and orderly?

Tags: c#

how do I make the base64 string neat and orderly?

example string abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz :

YWJjZGVmZ2hpamtsbW5vcHFyc3R1dnd4eXo =

(wrong)

YWJjZGVmZ2hpamtsb

W5vcHFyc3R1dnd4eXo =

(right)

I convert a string to base64 using Convert.ToBase64String (text), but the results are not neat and very long.

my code :

```
public static string encryptText(string text, int keysize, string publickeyxml)
{
  var data = algorithm(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text), keysize, publicKeyxml);
  return Convert.ToBase64String(data);
}


public static byte[] algorithm(byte[] text, int keysize, string publickeyxml)
{
  using (var provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(keysize))
  {
  provider.FromXmlString(publickeyxml);
  return provider.Encrypt(text, OAEP);
  }
}

string plaintext = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
ciphertext =  encryptText(plaintext, keysize, publickey);

string ciphertext;
string publickey = "mypublickey"
```

output = kZbKD35+uxg5mhcXjWTmBtF5xhIjIZ0SVbI2bsUHdcO+Pe9/n0MSaKcKznNJkR1hxvbCTfBnUnQ5zoLZ9pjW/s99qqPmwsha5EoMIXphljPLVPFA31aB9MKuqyW4rynf8MzR9cDK2N3nfsNnGS54OdnSVmwaS1mYiEP6Fhu2qjFAxwbu6RVyD5yuqYTVDYSxo99P2sJBHrSO2MaNeZSRyPCmu7rTqpZ6zxSVYETGS9Bfc1XbKq/ujA8SZB68Lmy/KTqEqXrGpKcw6vXxAca2phRcT92s70K7zOoF2+L5WrHN8fH9zMXnB64JjARVrNPkTrRPZS1pYu8USZNnla5Qaw==

Comment: Define "neat". There are not supposed to be line breaks in a base64 representation of data, and no-one in their right mind would try to "read" a base64 string. You process them in a program, so nobody cares what they look like.

Comment: `ToBase64String(data, Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks)`?

Comment: Note that you are probably not converting a string to base64, but a bytearray, that is, if you are actually using a decent encryption algorithm.

Comment: Don't look at it, there is no point.

Comment: When you encode something to base64, it has one and only one correct result. You cannot make it a different result because you think it is not neat. It's like asking "I am adding 2 numbers but I don't think the result is neat. How can I make it neat?"

Comment: i mean like, word wrap

Comment: thankyou @GSerg , this works

Answer (score 0):

This is what I mean, thank you @GSerg

```
Convert.ToBase64String(data, Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks)
```